# Not getting all elements from page selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Simple Amazon scrape here. Strangely this is not getting all the search results on the page. I am searching by `h2`. If I go to search page it does. Once, I enter a price range and search a new page loads..it doesn't seem to find all the results, I get 5 or 6 although there are many more. Any help?

```
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1700)")
    time.sleep(4)
    divs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
    for div in divs:
        items.append(div.text)
```

Comment: Why do you need `WebDriverWait()` when you are availing the benefit of `time.sleep(5)`, `time.sleep(3)`, `time.sleep(4)`, etc.

Comment: sorry...That was for the accept cookies button..The program is still not working...I am still testing it..so going to change..

Comment: If you increase the time of the 2nd sleep (after the scroll), are you then able to fetch all the H2 you expect? (If so, we'll work on a correct wait, instead of the sleep)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it.

```
for i in range(8):
        html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Soup failed. So did Webdriverwait, So did driver.execute_script('scroll to the bottom')